# How to get the total of two cross-tab tables

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a C# crystal report presenting employee salaries.
A cross-tab table is showing these data.
Earnings and Deductions are grouped by earn_deduct category (Here E & D).
Column is showing the employee number and the row shows the earn/deduct type

Now I want to calculate the Net Salary where I have to subtract the deductions from the earnings and display in same format
.This is easy if I can extract the totals from each groups(Total deductions and Total Earnings)

```
Earnings
```

[image: Earnings]

```
Deductions
```

[image]

Eg:- For Employee 219

```
Total Earnigs=66325.00
Total Deductions=12659.00
Net Salary=66325.00-12659.00
          =53666.00
```

Please give me a way to extract those two Totals from the relative cross tab table or any idea to get this total.

Comment: are these cross tabs included in group or where these are placed?

Comment: Yes .. its the same cross tab in a group (earn_deduct category)

Comment: @ Siva .. Could you please give me any idea for the below link/question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37718879/crystal-reports-pagewise-totals

Comment: yes.. yesterday I have seen this question but hesitated to comment as I am not sure if that is possible because you are forcing the cross tab to print total at the end of every page where page break is dynamic and cross tab itself is dynamic in nature... Will try today at my end and will let you know if I am able to achive what you have requested

Comment: @SIVA The following link works with me fine .. but for first time only.When ever I refresh the data in report it stops showing the first ,second sections in my group.May be useful link to get an idea.

http://www.logicaltrinkets.com/wordpress/?p=319

Comment: If it works fine then you refresh N number of times you should get the same result, What exactly are you doing in refresing and is there any data change while you refresh? Also, Thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

Go to report footer and place a cross tabl there.

In that take same columns as you took for individual cross tabls and take caculated member there write your formula `earnings-deductions`

To get calculated member go to preview and then at total column rightclick and insert calcualted member after that edit that column and write your formula

Edit... Below lnk doesn't has any use for this answer pasting so that we can save the link for future reference if comment is deleted.

To achive cross tab wrapping for page break up use the below link and tanks for code_Finder who provided the link

logicaltrinkets.com/wordpress/?p=319